# Can't upload .wav file from safari browser, chrome worked using angular 7

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, blob, angular7, form-data

I'm using angular 7 as frontend and node js as backend, and I need to upload audio file to s3. When I upload .wav audio files from safari browser its showing internal server error, and when I look on the formdata which I have sent with post URL having an error like I have attached. The issue is only when try to upload .wav file from safari browser and works when trying with .mp3 files. And all type of files worked in chrome.
[image: server error like]

[image: Formdata error]

Here is the code,
**upload-file.component.html**

```
<input type='file' id="imageUpload" accept=".mp3,.wav,audio/wav,audio/x-wav" style="display: none;" #fileInput
    (change)="uploadTracks($event)" />
```

**upload-file.component.ts**

```
uploadTracks(event) {
var re = /(?:\.([^.]+))?$/;

if (re.exec(event.target.files[0].name)[1] != 'mp3' && re.exec(event.target.files[0].name)[1] != 'wav') {
  this._snackBar.open('Please add mp3 files', '', {
    duration: 2000,
  });
} else {
  var files = event.srcElement.files;
  this.loadingbar = true;

  var video = document.createElement('audio');
  video.preload = 'metadata';
  let duration;
  video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', (res,) => {
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(video.src);
    duration = video.duration;
    this.addNewSongService.trackUpload(
      event,
      this.uploadurl,
      duration
    );
  });
  video.src = URL.createObjectURL(files[0]);

  this.fileName = event.target.files;
  this._addNewSongService.trackArraySubscribed.subscribe((res) => {
    this.fileUrl = res;
  });

  this._addNewSongService.listingArrayTracks.subscribe((track) => {
    this._addNewAlbum.getLoggedInDetails.emit(track);
    this.fileUrl === '' || this.fileUrl === undefined
      ? (this.fileUrl = track)
      : console.log('track already set', this.fileUrl);
    if (track != '' && track != undefined) {
      this.uploadedUrl = event.target.files[0].name;
    }
  });
}
```

}

**addNewSongService.ts**

```
trackUpload(event, url, duration): Observable<any> {
var s = true;
const fileList: FileList = event.target.files;
this.tracks = '';
if (fileList.length > 0) {
  const file: File = fileList[0];
  if (
    file.type != 'image/gif' &&
    file.type != 'image/tiff' &&
    file.type != 'image/jpeg' &&
    file.type != 'image/png'
  ) {
    const file_ext = file.name.substr(file.name.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
    const fileName = file.name.split('.').slice(0, -1).join('.');
    
    this.new_file_name =
      'Single_tracks/' + new Date().getTime() / 1000 + '.' + file_ext;

    const formData: FormData = new FormData();

    formData.append('uploadFile', file, this.new_file_name);
    console.log("formData==", formData)
    this.http
      .post(url, formData)
      .pipe()
      .subscribe(
        (data) => {
          this.tracks = {
            trackName: data['result'].files.uploadFile[0].name,
            trackLength: duration,
            fileName:fileName
          };
          this.trackList.next(this.tracks);
          this.uploadUrl.next(this.tracks);
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log("trackUpload error==", error)
        },
      );
  } else {
    return observableThrowError('This file type not supported');
  }
}
```

}

Please help